How to determine number of service dates and days between two snapshots in a dataframe?
I'm trying to take data from a nearly-weekly snapshot [some weeks are missing due to holidays, server issues, etc.] and determine the number of service dates between one snapshot and the next. I have a calendar of all dates of service to reference, but I have no idea where to begin with finding the number of dates in the calendar between one data snapshot and the next. I also need to determine the number of days the service actually ran [some only run Monday-Wednesday, for example] so I can calculate the total mileage each route drove during the period of the study.
I have a minimum dataset below. The actual dataset is about half a million rows for this fiscal year.
Toy Data / MWE
### Minimum Working Example
## Required Packages
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

## Setup the calendar of dates where we need to track mileage
calendar_mwe <- 
  tibble(date = seq.Date(ymd(20240520), ymd(20240801), by = "day")) %>% 
  mutate(day = weekdays(date),
         summer = case_when(date <= "2024-06-16" ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)) %>% 
  filter(!day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), 
         !date %in% c(
           ymd(20240527), # Memorial Day
           seq.Date(ymd(20240617), ymd(20240621), by = "day"), # Break week
           ymd(20240704) # Independence Day
         ))

## Setup a working example of raw data
# Set rand seed
set.seed(12345)

# Create raw route data
runroute_mwe <- 
  tibble(
    route_id = rep(100:119, 4),
    # Dates the snapshots were taken, including some missing weeks
    dates = rep(c(ymd(20240521), ymd(20240528), ymd(20240618), ymd(20240702)), each = 20),
    # Distance the route traveled
    route_dist = rep(runif(20, min = 0.5, max = 12), 4),
    # Number of days that route was in service [assume 1 = Mon, 2 = Mon-Tue, 3 = Mon-Wed etc.]
    route_days = rep(sample.int(5, size = 20, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1, .1, .1, .1, .6)), 4)
  ) %>% 
  mutate( # Set a change to mileage based on dates to mimic actual data
    route_dist = case_when(
      dates == min(dates) ~ route_dist + runif(1, min = 1, max = 2),
      dates == max(dates) ~ route_dist - runif(1, min = 1, max = 2),
      TRUE ~ route_dist
    )
  )

> head(calendar_mwe)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  date       day       summer
  <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
1 2024-05-20 Monday         0
2 2024-05-21 Tuesday        0
3 2024-05-22 Wednesday      0
4 2024-05-23 Thursday       0
5 2024-05-24 Friday         0
6 2024-05-28 Tuesday        0

> head(runroute_mwe)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  route_id dates      route_dist route_days
     <int> <date>          <dbl>      <int>
1      100 2024-05-21      10.6           5
2      101 2024-05-21      12.4           5
3      102 2024-05-21      11.0           1
4      103 2024-05-21      12.5           4
5      104 2024-05-21       7.53          3
6      105 2024-05-21       4.20          5

Things I've Tried
From here, I can determine the number of days between each snapshot as follows:
## Number of days between snapshots
runroute_daysbtwn <- runroute_mwe %>% 
  nest(.by = dates) %>% 
  mutate(days_between = difftime(lead(dates, 1), dates, units = "day"))

> head(runroute_daysbtwn)
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  dates      data              days_between
  <date>     <list>            <drtn>      
1 2024-05-21 <tibble [20 × 3]>  7 days     
2 2024-05-28 <tibble [20 × 3]> 21 days     
3 2024-06-18 <tibble [20 × 3]> 14 days     
4 2024-07-02 <tibble [20 × 3]> NA days 

This is great-ish: It gives me the number of calendar days between each snapshot, minus the last snapshot [which is fine, since we don't have another snapshot after that one yet]. What it doesn't give me is the number of service days as defined by calendar_mwe.
So, this morning, I thought to try something else:
## Snapshot start and end dates
runroute_datesbtwn <- runroute_mwe %>% 
  nest(.by = dates) %>% 
  mutate(end_date = as.Date(lead(dates) - days(1)),
         end_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(end_date), dates, end_date)))

## Number of dates in calendar between the start and end dates
for (i in 1:nrow(runroute_datesbtwn)) {
  runroute_calendar <- calendar_mwe %>% 
    filter(between(date, runroute_datesbtwn$dates[i], runroute_datesbtwn$end_date[i])) %>% 
    nrow()
  
  runroute_datesbtwn$dates_between[i] <- runroute_calendar
}

> head(runroute_datesbtwn)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  dates      data              end_date   dates_between
  <date>     <list>            <date>             <int>
1 2024-05-21 <tibble [20 × 3]> 2024-05-27             4
2 2024-05-28 <tibble [20 × 3]> 2024-06-17            14
3 2024-06-18 <tibble [20 × 3]> 2024-07-01             6
4 2024-07-02 <tibble [20 × 3]> 2024-07-02             1

This works well and gives me the number of service dates between each snapshot. The unnest()ed version of runroute_datesbtwn now looks like this:
> head(unnest(runroute_datesbtwn, everything()))
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  dates      route_id route_dist route_days end_date   dates_between
  <date>        <int>      <dbl>      <int> <date>             <int>
1 2024-05-21      100      10.6           5 2024-05-27             4
2 2024-05-21      101      12.4           5 2024-05-27             4
3 2024-05-21      102      11.0           1 2024-05-27             4
4 2024-05-21      103      12.5           4 2024-05-27             4
5 2024-05-21      104       7.53          3 2024-05-27             4
6 2024-05-21      105       4.20          5 2024-05-27             4

The Problem
Okay, so now I have the run/route information, a calendar, the start and end dates for each snapshot, and the number of service dates between each snapshot. If every run/route ran Monday-Friday, this would be all I'd need to calculate total mileage driven for each run and route. The problem comes in with one of the initial columns in runroute_mwe: route_days.
Here, we assume that if route_days = 1 then the run only operated on Mondays, if route_days = 2 then the run operated Monday-Tuesday, if route_days = 3 then the run operated Monday-Wednesday, and so forth barring dates in the calendar where no runs occurred.
For the first snapshot, it's easy to say that I just subtract 1 from route_days when I go to calculate a new column of total distance traveled [e.g. total_dist = (route_days - 1) * route_dist] since the dates between the two snapshots are Tuesday-Friday. This won't work for any of the other snapshots, however, so I feel stuck.
I feel like I need to find some way to get the number of each weekday between the snapshots, but I'm not sure how to go about that. I'd imagine a df with additional <int> columns for a count of each weekday [M-F] which would allow me to do some ridiculous case_when() statement to make my final calculations, though that all seems rather cumbersome.
EDIT: Re-wrote question, MWE, toy data, and things I've tried to hopefully be more clear with what my problem is and where I need assistance. This morning I was able to make some headway on the initial problem, but it's still not solved.

Small typo in your example. You defined calendar not calendar_mwe. Is the end or start date not inclusive? Looks like in calendar between 2024-05-21 and 2024-05-28 there are five service days (if both start/end are included).

Thank you, I changed the definition to calendar_mwe in the setup. The dates wouldn't be inclusive in both directions because then we'd be double-counting 2024-05-28 as that's the start of a new snapshot.

What is the origin in ... as.Date() %>%?

I appreciate you putting the time into providing the details of what you have tried, but as is, it's hard to really understand your problem. Would you provide a toy dataset, and show your desired output for it, instead of providing hypothetical examples (i.e. Fridays, for example, when route_days == 4).

How do you handle the last day of a route in runroute_mwe? For example the last value of dates for route_id == 100 is 2024-07-02. So that snapshot starts 2024-07-02, but when does it end?

@LMc The 2024-07-02 snapshot will end when the next one is taken next week. For now, the mileage calculation should simply end at 2024-07-02 and not progress from there.

@M-- The as.Date() %>% call was added because the following filter(value %in% calendar_mwe$date) didn't work without it.  I'm not sure what you mean with your other comment. I did provide a toy dataset in the mwe setup. You can ignore my comment about filtering Fridays, that's for a future step once this problem is solved. I need to determine the number of days we provided service between each snapshot.

@Morrigan So are you only trying to count the number of days in a complete run? For example, if route_days is 2 and the days of the week for the service dates that fall within a snapshot are "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday" you would want an N = 2 since Friday is not in the Monday-Tuesday run? I think what is left out of your edit is the expected output given the data you have provided.

Your question has been reopened. Please move your solution to the Your Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer.

SOLVED
Okay, so I managed to solve this question for myself. I did end up going the route I indicated in my last paragraph above. See code below for my solution. If anyone has a better solution for my problem, please let me know.
## Additional package requirement
library(fuzzyjoin)

## Snapshot start and end dates
runroute_datesbtwn_temp <- runroute_mwe %>% 
  nest(.by = dates) %>% 
  mutate(end_date = as.Date(lead(dates) - days(1)),
         end_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(end_date), dates, end_date))) %>% 
  select(start_date = dates, end_date)

## Fuzzy join calendar_mwe to runroute_datesbtwn
runroute_calendar <- calendar_mwe %>% 
  # This gives me the calendar with identified start_date and end_date for each snapshot in runroute_mwe
  fuzzy_left_join(
    runroute_datesbtwn_temp,
    by = c(
      "date" = "start_date",
      "date" = "end_date"
    ),
    match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)
  ) %>% 
  # Filter out the null values
  filter(!is.na(start_date)) %>% 
  # Create a column for each day
  mutate(
    mon = ifelse(day == "Monday",    1, 0),
    tue = ifelse(day == "Tuesday",   1, 0),
    wed = ifelse(day == "Wednesday", 1, 0),
    thu = ifelse(day == "Thursday",  1, 0),
    fri = ifelse(day == "Friday",    1, 0)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(start_date, end_date, summer) %>% 
  # Determine the number of that weekday occurring in each snapshot
  summarise(
    mon = sum(mon),
    tue = sum(tue),
    wed = sum(wed),
    thu = sum(thu),
    fri = sum(fri),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

> head(runroute_calendar)
# A tibble: 4 × 8
  start_date end_date   summer   mon   tue   wed   thu   fri
  <date>     <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2024-05-21 2024-05-27      0     0     1     1     1     1
2 2024-05-28 2024-06-17      0     2     3     3     3     3
3 2024-06-18 2024-07-01      1     2     1     1     1     1
4 2024-07-02 2024-07-02      1     0     1     0     0     0

From here, it was a simple case of a quick join, unnest, and mutate to get the data I actually needed:
runroute_datesbtwn <- runroute_datesbtwn %>% 
  # Join in the new calendar with the count of weekdays per snapshot
  left_join(
    runroute_calendar,
    by = c(
      "dates" = "start_date",
      "end_date" = "end_date"
    )
  ) %>% 
  unnest(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Calculate the actual number of days the route ran
    # This was the initial problem I was trying to solve here
    route_days_tot = case_when(
      route_days == 5 ~ select(., mon:fri) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE),
      route_days == 4 ~ select(., mon:thu) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE),
      route_days == 3 ~ select(., mon:wed) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE),
      route_days == 2 ~ select(., mon:tue) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE),
      route_days == 1 ~ select(., mon)     %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
    ),
    # Calculate the total mileage
    total_mileage = route_days_tot * route_dist
  ) %>% 
  # Select columns for final output
  select(
    snapshot_date = dates,
    route_id,
    route_dist,
    route_days,
    total_mileage
  )

> head(runroute_datesbtwn)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  snapshot_startdate snapshot_enddate route_id route_dist route_days total_mileage
  <date>             <date>              <int>      <dbl>      <int>         <dbl>
1 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            100      10.6           5          42.3
2 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            101      12.4           5          49.4
3 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            102      11.0           1           0  
4 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            103      12.5           4          37.4
5 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            104       7.53          3          15.1
6 2024-05-21         2024-05-27            105       4.20          5          16.8


Perhaps:
library(dplyr)

runroute_mwe |> 
  mutate(next_date = lead(dates), .by = route_id) |>
  filter(!is.na(next_date)) |>
  left_join(select(calendar_mwe, date), 
            by = join_by(between(y$date, x$dates, x$next_date, bounds = "[)"))) |>
  group_by(pick(all_of(names(runroute_mwe)))) |>
  summarize(service_dates = list(date), service_snap = n(), .groups = "drop")
#   route_id dates      route_dist route_days service_dates service_snap
#      <int> <date>          <dbl>      <int> <list>               <int>
# 1      100 2024-05-21      10.6           5 <date [4]>               4
# 2      100 2024-05-28       8.79          5 <date [14]>             14
# 3      100 2024-06-18       8.79          5 <date [6]>               6
# 4      101 2024-05-21      12.4           5 <date [4]>               4
# 5      101 2024-05-28      10.6           5 <date [14]>             14
# 6      101 2024-06-18      10.6           5 <date [6]>               6
# ...

I left the service_dates list-column in the output. This shows what dates from calendar_mwe fall within the snapshots. However, I think you need to clarify your question as I am not sure the output you posted matches the data you have provided.
